# Getting index in NSMutableArray of selected or tapped image

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am developing an app where I add images to an `NSMutableArray` and  display them in an image view.

My problem is that I will don't know how to get the index of the selected or tapped image in my app.

```
FrontsCards=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"cloub1.png",@"cloub2.png",@"cloub3.png",@"cloub4.png", nil];

for(int m=0; m< [FrontsCards count];m++)
{
    NSString *imageName=[FrontsCards objectAtIndex:m];

    NSString *fullImageName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",imageName];

    int padding=25;

    CGRect imageViewFrame=CGRectMake(scrollView.frame.size.width*m+padding, scrollView.frame.origin.y, scrollView.frame.size.width-2*padding, scrollView.frame.size.height);

    ImgView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:imageViewFrame];

    [ImgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:fullImageName]];

    [ImgView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];


    [scrollView addSubview:ImgView];


    UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doubleTapImgView:)];
    doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
    doubleTap.delegate = self;

    [self.ImgView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];

    self.ImgView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;    
}


CGSize scrollViewSize=CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width*[FrontsCards count], scrollView.frame.size.height);
[scrollView setContentSize:scrollViewSize];
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];
```

What should I do in my tap gesture recognizer to get the index of the image?

```
- (void)doubleTapImgView:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
     NSLog(@"double-tap");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you can use something like this:

```
first add the name of the image as the accessibilityIdentifier of the the imageview
[imgView setAccessibilityIdentifier:imageName];
```

then in the tapRecognizer:

```
-(void)doubleTapImgView:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture{
    UIImageView *imgView = (UIImageView *)gesture.view;
     int idx = [FrontCards indexOfObject:[imgView accessibilityIdentifier]];
}
```

Comment: In this case gesture.view will give the ImageView and in the FrontCards array is a consist of UIImages. So it won't give give you the index. Just want you to know :)

Comment: @Ushan87 Thanks! updated my code maybe this can work now. I used the accessibiltyIdentifier :)

Answer (score 1):

set a tag to each imageView you using like this :

```
ImgView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:imageViewFrame];
ImgView.tag = m;
```

and then replace this method:

```
- (void)doubleTapImgView:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
     NSLog(@"double-tap");
     NSLog(@"%d", gesture.view.tag);
}
```

it will print you the **index** of the image in the **imageView**

Comment: if you want to support me help me to increase mu reputation.